# Nuxt choosing layout before initialize

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I use nuxt-generate and nuxt/device package. which provides the device type but for the layout since I use nuxt-generate at first load app uses default layout. not the one provided by nuxt/device. but after i go another page it starts using correct layout. so the problem is how can i have the app use layout at first initialize. or at least change it after initialize. is there any way to do these?
this is how i try to choose layout but never works at first open.

```
layout (context) {
    if(context.isMobile) {
        return 'mobile'
    } else if (context.isDesktop) {
        return 'default'
    } 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use nuxt-generate nuxt generates a series of static html files, I don't think there is an easy way to solve this, but there can be a series of workarounds:

- use nuxt in **ssr mode**, so that you have a way of knowing who is calling that particular resource
- make a distinction at the level of routes like (/desktop/*** and /mobile/***) where both routes lead to a different layout and in the webserver configuration do a **redirect** on the correct route
- do a middleware that redirects to the correct route /desktop /mobile, but I don't recommend it because you lose the advantage of static generation of nuxt

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.